# why can't I access value NODE_ENV in my server.js file when I have set it gruntfile.js with grunt-env

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to set up some options using env in my gruntfile.js so that I can use NODE_ENV based if statements in my server.js file.

I have installed grunt-env using "npm grunt-env --save-dev" and included and env section in gruntfile.js:

```
 grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    env: {
        dev: {
            NODE_ENV : 'development'
        },
        prod: {
            NODE_ENV : 'production'
        }
    },
    ....
```

I also registered the tasks for dev and production at the end of the file

```
   grunt.registerTask('dev', ['csslint', 'jshint', 'nodeunit', 'sass', 'concurrent', 'nodemon']);
   grunt.registerTask('prod', ['cssmin', 'uglify', 'nodemon']);
```

When I run "grunt dev" or "grunt prod" the server starts without error and starts the correct tasks, but I am still not able to access NODE_ENV form inside my server.js file. I tried adding the following:

```
 console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

this returns as "undefined" no matter if I use "grunt dev" or "grunt prod"

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your grunt-env task before all the order tasks;

```
grunt.registerTask('dev', ['env:dev', 'csslint', 'jshint', 'nodeunit', 'sass', 'concurrent', 'nodemon']);
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['env:prod', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'nodemon']);
```

Comment: Thanks!, this was missing from the example I followed but now you point it out its seems to obvious. :)